# Crossmark on an expression inside mathmode in latex

Tags: math-mode, symbols

How can I put a crossmark on an expression inside a math mode using latex like below?
[image]

Comment: you may choose to use `\nrightarrow` instead, which produces this:

http://i.stack.imgur.com/b7NXd.png

Comment: @FarZin : \nrightarrow produces a left slash. I would like to put a crossmark on the arrow.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe this is overkill, but you can build the operator with `\times` overlaid on `\longrightarrow` with

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\def\longxrightarrow{\mathrel{%
    \mathchoice{\LongXRightArrow}{\LongXRightArrow}{\scriptsize\LongXRightArrow}{\tiny\LongXRightArrow}%
}}
\def\LongXRightArrow{{%
    \setbox0\hbox{\ensuremath{\longrightarrow}}%
    \rlap{\hbox to \wd0{\ensuremath{\hss\times\hss}}}\box0
}}



\begin{document}

$   a^b  \longxrightarrow c^d $

\end{document}
```

to appear as

[image: longxrightarrow]

Answer (score 6):

### `\nrightarrow` + mirrored `\nrightarrow`

Maybe the cross is a little small, at least the size and position of the cross comes from a font designer, because the example overlays `\nrightarrow` with a mirrored version of it:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\crossrightarrow}{%
  \mathrel{%
    \mathpalette\@crossrightarrow{}%
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\@crossrightarrow}[2]{%
  % #1: math style
  % #2: unused
  \sbox0{$#1\nrightarrow\m@th$}%
  \sbox2{$#1\vcenter{}$}%
  \sbox2{\raisebox{\ht2}{\scalebox{1}[-1]{\raisebox{-\ht2}{\copy0}}}}%
  \ht2=\ht0 %
  \dp2=\dp2 %
  \rlap{\unhcopy2}%
  \copy0 %
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[
  a^b \crossrightarrow a^c
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

### `\rightarrow` + `\setminus` + mirrored `\setminus`

A variant with a larger cross (for my taste it is too large):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\crossrightarrow}{%
  \mathrel{%
    \mathpalette\@crossrightarrow{}%
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\@crossrightarrow}[2]{%
  \sbox0{$#1\rightarrow\m@th$}%
  \sbox2{$#1\setminus\m@th$}%
  \copy0 %
  \kern-\wd0 %
  \hbox to \wd0{%
    \hspace{0pt plus 1fil}%
    \rlap{\scalebox{-1}[1]{\copy2}}%
    \copy2 %
    \hspace{0pt plus 1.5fil}%                                           
    % the factor for `fil' controls the horizontal position of the cross
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[
  a^b \crossrightarrow a^c
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**Remarks:**

- `\mathpalette` is used to get an adoption of the symbol to the four math styles.

Answer (score 4):

A simpler way to overlap `\times` to a long right arrow:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\longxarrow}[1]{%
  \mathrel{\vphantom{\to}\mathpalette\longx@rrow{#1}}% arrows are bigger than \times
}
\newcommand{\longx@rrow}[2]{%
  \ooalign{\hidewidth$#1\times\m@th$\hidewidth\cr$#1#2\m@th$\cr}%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\longxrightarrow}{\longxarrow{\longrightarrow}}
\newcommand{\longxleftarrow}{\longxarrow{\longleftarrow}}

\begin{document}

$A\longxrightarrow B_{\longxrightarrow}$

$A\longxleftarrow B_{\longxleftarrow}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One illustration that we can enter math mode with TikZ or we could typeset the formulae completely in it using a couple of nodes.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}\pagestyle{empty}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\def\halfwidthx{3ex}
\def\halfwidthy{1ex}
\tikzset{mystyle/.style={red,xshift=0.4*\halfwidthx}}
\begin{document}
$a^b
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[green,-{Stealth[blue]},line width=.15ex] (0,0)--(2*\halfwidthx,0);
\draw[mystyle] (0,1ex)--(\halfwidthx,-\halfwidthy);
\draw[mystyle] (0,-1ex)--(\halfwidthx,\halfwidthy);
\end{tikzpicture}
c^d$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
$a^b 
  \mathrel{\stackengine{-1.3pt}{$\rightarrow$}%
    {\color{red}\scalebox{1.6}{$\times$}\kern3pt}{O}{c}{F}{T}{L}} 
a^c$
\end{document}
```

[image]